# Koin Android Test

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, koin

I have a problem with Koin & "androidTest".
Because androidTest starts the Application I don't need to start Koin by myself in the test.

Now I need to inject a mock service. The problem is, that I inject inside of a method with `get()` inside of a singleton class and this is not working via constructor injection because the injected object can have different implementations.

My idea was to declare what I need this way:

```
declare {
        factory<Webservice>(override = true) { mockWebservice }
    }
```

But this will be applied on all tests. That's why an other test, which checks if the correct class was injected failed.

I also tried to use `stopKoin()`, `startKoin(listOf(appModule))` in the `@After` method, but with this the dependency injection doesn't work anymore in later tests.

Is there a way to declare the mock only for one test?

Comment: So you want to declare `mockWebService` only for that test ?

Comment: yes, but it looks like it's not possible without a special application class for testing or something like this

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I do it in my Android Tests:

In a parent test class, I use these methods for setup and teardown:

```
@Before fun startKoinForTest() {
    if (GlobalContext.getOrNull() == null) {
        startKoin {
            androidLogger()
            androidContext(application)
            modules(appComponent)
        }
    }
}

@After fun stopKoinAfterTest() = stopKoin()
```

My appcomponent contains all modules needed for the dependency tree.

Then, when I want to mock a dependency for a specific test, I use something like this:

```
declareMock<TripApi> { given(this.fetch(any())).willReturn(TestData.usaTrip) }
```

You will need to add a new mock declaration for each test if you wish to swap a dependency with a mock.

Edit: Application is gotten this way:

```
protected val instrumentationContext: Context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
protected val application = instrumentationContext.applicationContext as Application
```

Comment: where do you get `application` from?

Comment: @OleksandrNos
Check answer edit

Answer (score 2):

To declare mock only for one test you can use [loadKoinModules()](https://insert-koin.io/docs/1.0/documentation/reference/index.html#_loading_modules_without_startkoin_function)

> You can’t call the startKoin() function more than once. But you can use directly the loadKoinModules() functions.

So this way your definition will override default one

```
loadKoinModules(module {
    factory<Webservice>(override = true) { mockWebservice }
})
```

Also, don't forget to implement `KoinTest` interface in  you test class

Comment: Thanks for the answer but if i do this, an other test in an other class fails:

demoMode.activate()
            val webservice: Webservice = get()
            assertTrue(webservice is DemoWebservice)