# java.lang.IllegalStateException: KoinApplication has not been started

Tags: kotlin, koin

I am learning kotlin using koin. While running the application in catlog I see the following message.

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: KoinApplication has not been started**

though I have used **startKoin** in MyApplication

```
class MyApplication : Application() {

    var listOfModules = module {
        single { GitHubServiceApi() }
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        startKoin {
            androidLogger()
            androidContext(this@MyApplication)
            modules(listOfModules)
        }

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Found where I have done my mistake. Thanks to everyone

Comment: What is your new error?please explain more and completely

Comment: i am having this issue in only one device ? c

Comment: I am having this issue only on my Galaxy s10 :l

Comment: If `Compose` preview shows this error, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72446056/jetpack-compose-preview-not-working-when-using-koin-for-dependency-injection.

Comment: @CoolMind thanks for sharing exactly where I was; Compose. Alas, solutions on that link dont work either.

Comment: @sud007, thank you for an answer. Agree with you, I also didn't solve the problem. Probably continued to work without Preview or removed Koin injections from that Screen (instantiated objects directly). Also there is a way to check if this is a Preview. See https://github.com/google/accompanist/issues/1498: `val isInspection = LocalInspectionMode.current`.

Answer (score 18):

Adding "android:name=".TheApplication" in the Manifest file solved the issue.

```
    android:name=".TheApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_app_icon_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Shrine">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

"android:name=".TheApplication" is the Class Name from Koin

```
class TheApplication : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
        }

        startKoin {
            androidLogger()
            androidContext(androidContext = this@TheApplication)

            modules(
                listOfModules
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I already have this tag, any other way to fix this ?

Comment: I have already added this but it does not help.

Answer (score 9):

In you manifest.xml,

```
<application>
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    ...
</application
```

Add this line in application tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you write unit test, you also should add `startKoin` and inject dependencies:

```
@Before
fun startKoinForTest() {
    startKoin {
        modules(DI.modules(...))
    }
}

@After
fun stopKoinAfterTest() = stopKoin()
```

See also [Koin Android Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52819199/koin-android-test).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to give the name of the class where you called startKoin() method, in the Manifest as an application name. And this will let your configure logging, properties loading and modules. Check this out: https://doc.insert-koin.io/#/koin-core/dsl

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun getKoin(activity: ComponentActivity): Koin {
return if (activity is KoinComponent) {
    activity.getKoin()
} else {
    GlobalContext.getOrNull() ?: startKoin {
        androidContext(activity)
        modules(listModule)
    }.koin
}
```

}

```
 fun ComponentActivity.contextAwareActivityScope() = runCatching {
LifecycleScopeDelegate<Activity>(
    lifecycleOwner = this,
    koin = getKoin(this)
)}.getOrElse { activityScope() 
}
```